# Set Background Image to UILabel Properly in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel, background-image

So How you will set a background image to UILabel.

Here is the ways i have tried after googling and reading some of Stackoverflow posts.

I have a image and want to fit / shrink according to size of UILabel.

**1 --**

```
lblDelivery.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tick.png"]];
```

and result is :

[image]

**2 --**

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Tick.png"];
CGSize imgSize = lblDelivery.frame.size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( imgSize );
[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,imgSize.width,imgSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
lblDelivery.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];
```

and result is :

[image]

Please help on this issue. how to i can get this image in BG perfectly

Comment: Does it have to be a `UILabel`? Use `UIImageView` instead. Or you could just be lazy and change the text to this ✓ and select your desired text colour.

Comment: Use a custom button with no action, changing the behaviour of currents controls isn't properly

Comment: @jammycoder your idea is just awesome ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a custom button rather than label having no action against button.

For that you can use this piece of code to set the background image, and it will be stratched automatically.

```
[yourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Although There is no action against this button, you may also disable user intraction on this button as

```
yourButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```